# Is it possible to monitor discovering process when using Google Nearby Connections 2.0?

Tags: android, bluetooth, google-nearby

I have been playing around with Google Nearby Connections 2.0 sample program: walkietalkie. I ran the APP on several android phones and tablets. I usually put one device on advertising mode and other devices in discovering mode very close by. The devices sometimes discover successfully but also fail to discover frequently.

Is there a way to monitor the Bluetooth discovering process to get more information? I suspect Bluetooth pairing issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter for the log tags 'NearbyConnections' and 'NearbyMediums'

```
adb logcat NearbyConnections:* NearbyMediums:* *:S
```

That will print out any warnings and/or errors that occur. If you find a device that's particularly troublesome, give me the model number and I'll add it to our test suite. [Disclaimer: I work on Nearby Connections]

Comment: Thanks. I will try that