# Cannot discover Raspberry pi using Nearby api

Tags: android, google-api, raspberry-pi3, android-things, google-nearby

I am working on a project where I have to use Google's Nearby API to communicate between Raspberry pi3 (working on Android things) and android mobile. I started advertising service on Raspberry pi3 and discovery service on mobile successfully. But I can't discover Raspberry pi3 on my mobile. Here is my code-

On **Raspberry pi3**:

```
private void startAdvertizing() {

    logging("advertizing initiated");



    Nearby.Connections.startAdvertising(mCLient,"Tinku",getString(R.string.service_id),mConnectionLifecycleCallback
                                        ,new AdvertisingOptions(Strategy.P2P_CLUSTER)).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Connections.StartAdvertisingResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull Connections.StartAdvertisingResult startAdvertisingResult) {
            if (startAdvertisingResult.getStatus().isSuccess()){
                logging("avertizind success");
            } else {
                logging(startAdvertisingResult.getStatus().getStatusMessage());
            }
        }
    });

}
```

On **mobile side**:

```
 private void startDicovery() {
    Log.d(TAG,"Initializing discovery");
    tv.setText("Initializing discovery");

    EndpointDiscoveryCallback mEndPointDiscoveryCallback = new EndpointDiscoveryCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onEndpointFound(String s, DiscoveredEndpointInfo discoveredEndpointInfo) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Endpoint found");
            tv.setText("Endpoint found");
        }

        @Override
        public void onEndpointLost(String s) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Endpoint Lost, "+s);
            tv.setText("Endpoint Lost, "+s);
        }
    };


    Nearby.Connections.startDiscovery(mCLient,getString(R.string.service_id),mEndPointDiscoveryCallback,new DiscoveryOptions(Strategy.P2P_CLUSTER))
                        .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                                if (status.isSuccess()){
                                    logging("Discovert success");
                                    isDiscovery = true;
                                } else {
                                    logging("Discovery failed "+ status.getStatusMessage());
                                    isDiscovery = false;
                                }
                            }
                        });

}
```

I don't know what I am missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I've seen this working before. There's a couple things you can try.

1) Check the logs. See [Is it possible to monitor discovering process when using Google Nearby Connections 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45551237/5623474)

2) Try it on two Android phones just to make sure the code works. The snippets look good, but you never know.

3) Send me the model & Android OS build version of your phone and your Android Things device.

Comment: It worked when I searched fro specific service id , but its sufficient for my project. Thank you